# Offer trial version for PHP software

Tags: php, obfuscation, trial, time-limiting

Am wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how to offer a trial downloadable version for a PHP software. I know Kayako and many other companies do so. Any suggestions?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

IonCube Encoder could be what you're after... http://www.ioncube.com/

Answer (score -2):

What's the use of **downloading** trial versions of **web-application**?
Isn't it supposed to run on a web-serer and your own one is perfect place to show all features live?

Comment: Yes, but many customers want to see if it fits well with their site and integrates smoothly into their system.